# Trouble with compiling c++ code in OpenCV - DisplayImage.cpp (using gcc and CMake)

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation

I'm following the codes given here http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html#linux-gcc-usage
This is compiling using GCC and CMAKE.

I saved a DisplayImage.cpp file with the code within and a CMakeLists.txt file with it's corresponding code. Also lena.jpeg was saved in the same directory.

Code for DisplayImage.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Code for CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Then I try to generate the executable using
    cmake .
    make

But I get the following error...

```
clive@clive-Aspire-4755:~/Visual_Odometry/cpp/DisplayImage$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/clive/Visual_Odometry/cpp/DisplayImage
clive@clive-Aspire-4755:~/Visual_Odometry/cpp/DisplayImage$ make
Scanning dependencies of target DisplayImage
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o
/home/clive/Visual_Odometry/cpp/DisplayImage/DisplayImage.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/clive/Visual_Odometry/cpp/DisplayImage/DisplayImage.cpp:8:5: error: ‘arg’ was not declared in this scope
/home/clive/Visual_Odometry/cpp/DisplayImage/DisplayImage.cpp:8:5: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/complex:619:5: note:   ‘std::arg’
/home/clive/Visual_Odometry/cpp/DisplayImage/DisplayImage.cpp:25:11: error: ‘waitkey’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The DisplayImage executable doesn't get created due to some error. Can someone help me out here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To those who are facing this problem, try adding

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h>
```

to the top of DisplayImage.cpp code. Then compile and execute again.
Hope it works! I just tried and verified it myself now.